# Cannot configure test module when the test module has already been instantiated. Make sure not using `inject` before `TestBed.configureTestingModule`

Tags: angular, typescript, test

Estaba desarrollando una App en Angular, y estaba implementando la parte de testing de uno de los componentes que conforman la App.

El tema esq la App estaba funcionando bien, y derepente al intentar implementar un nuevo test, me he encontrado con el siguiente error que veis a continuación debajo:

Karma:`

```
Error: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject` before `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.
```

Y este es el archivo spec.ts:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { OrangeApi } from '@orange/redux';
import { EscaparateBannerComponent } from './escaparate-banner.component';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CurrentDataService } from '../../services/current-data.service';

describe('EscaparateBannerComponent', () => {
  let component: EscaparateBannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EscaparateBannerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EscaparateBannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.moduleData = require('../../testing/moduleData.json');
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const orangeApiStub = () => ({
      post: () => true,
      get: () => true
    });

    const CurrentDataServiceStub = () => ({
      getCurrentData: () => Observable.of({}),
      setCurrentData: () => Observable.of({}),
      setFullCurrentData: () => null
    });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ EscaparateBannerComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: OrangeApi, useFactory: orangeApiStub },
        { provide: CurrentDataService, useFactory: CurrentDataServiceStub }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
 
  //DONE
  it('getBannerModuleData', () =>{

     expect(component).toBeTruthy(); 

    spyOn(component, 'getBannerModuleData').and.callThrough();
    component.getBannerModuleData();
    expect(component.getBannerModuleData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    //DONE
    it('searchBanner', () => {

    spyOn(component, 'searchBanner').and.callThrough();
    component.getBannerModuleData();
    expect(component.searchBanner).toHaveBeenCalled();


    });
  });
```

Si teneís idea de por donde van los tiros gracias de ante mano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser un problema del orden en el que estas ejecutando las tareas dentro del `beforeEach`, prueba con este orden:

Al parecer estabas pidiendo datos del modulo y luego inicializandolo, asi que el orden importa, prueba asi a ver que tal va

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { OrangeApi } from '@orange/redux';
import { EscaparateBannerComponent } from './escaparate-banner.component';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CurrentDataService } from '../../services/current-data.service';

describe('EscaparateBannerComponent', () => {
    let component: EscaparateBannerComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<EscaparateBannerComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        const orangeApiStub = () => ({
            post: () => true,
            get: () => true
        });

        const CurrentDataServiceStub = () => ({
            getCurrentData: () => Observable.of({}),
            setCurrentData: () => Observable.of({}),
            setFullCurrentData: () => null
        });

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [EscaparateBannerComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: OrangeApi, useFactory: orangeApiStub },
                { provide: CurrentDataService, useFactory: CurrentDataServiceStub }
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EscaparateBannerComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.moduleData = require('../../testing/moduleData.json');
        fixture.detectChanges();
    }));

    //DONE
    it('getBannerModuleData', () => {

        expect(component).toBeTruthy();

        spyOn(component, 'getBannerModuleData').and.callThrough();
        component.getBannerModuleData();
        expect(component.getBannerModuleData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    //DONE
    it('searchBanner', () => {

        spyOn(component, 'searchBanner').and.callThrough();
        component.getBannerModuleData();
        expect(component.searchBanner).toHaveBeenCalled();


    });
});
```

Una recomendacion aparte es probar si los test que necesitas correr realmente necesitan un `beforeEach` en la incializacion del componente, puede que no sea necesario correrlos cada vez asi que puede que baste tan solo con un `beforeAll`, esto te puede mejorar la velocidad de ejecucion.

Comment: He probado a implementarlo, y ahora sale el siguiente error:import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { OrangeApi } from '@orange/redux';
import { EscaparateBannerComponent } from './escaparate-banner.component';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CurrentDataService } from '../../services/current-data.service';